# Setting Flag for an Email in ActiveSync

Tags: activesync

Trying to set status Flag for an email using ActiveSync. Below is my request. I receive status 6. What's wrong with my request?

**Request**

```
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:" xmlns:email="Email:" xmlns:tasks="Tasks:" >
 <Collections>
     <Collection>
         <SyncKey>648263900</SyncKey>
         <CollectionId>11</CollectionId>
         <GetChanges>0</GetChanges>
         <Commands>
             <Change>
                 <ServerId>11:2</ServerId>
                 <ApplicationData>
                      <email:Flag>
                         <email:Status>1</email:Status>
                         <email:FlagType>Follow Up</email:FlagType>
                         <tasks:StartDate>113-04-23T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:StartDate>
                         <tasks:UTCStartDate>113-04-23T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:UTCStartDate>
                         <tasks:DueDate>113-04-26T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:DueDate> 
                         <tasks:UTCDueDate>113-04-26T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:UTCDueDate>
                     </email:Flag>
                 </ApplicationData>
             </Change>
         </Commands>
     </Collection>
 </Collections>
```

**Response I receive**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ActiveSync PUBLIC "-//MICROSOFT//DTD ActiveSync//EN" "http://www.microsoft.com/">
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>648263900</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>11</CollectionId>
            <Status>1</Status>
            <Responses>
                <Change>
                    <ServerId>11:2</ServerId>
                    <Status>6</Status>
                </Change>
            </Responses>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Comment: the response should be in WBXML format right ? is this a decode version ?

Answer (score 1):

Change email:FlagType from `Follow Up` to `for Follow Up`.

And add `</Sync>` in the end.

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:" xmlns:email="Email:" xmlns:tasks="Tasks:" >
 <Collections>
     <Collection>
         <SyncKey>648263900</SyncKey>
         <CollectionId>11</CollectionId>
         <GetChanges>0</GetChanges>
         <Commands>
             <Change>
                 <ServerId>11:2</ServerId>
                 <ApplicationData>
                      <email:Flag>
                         <email:Status>1</email:Status>
                         <email:FlagType>for Follow Up</email:FlagType>
                         <tasks:StartDate>113-04-23T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:StartDate>
                         <tasks:UTCStartDate>113-04-23T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:UTCStartDate>
                         <tasks:DueDate>113-04-26T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:DueDate> 
                         <tasks:UTCDueDate>113-04-26T05:30:00.000Z</tasks:UTCDueDate>
                     </email:Flag>
                 </ApplicationData>
             </Change>
         </Commands>
     </Collection>
 </Collections>
</Sync>
```

See more: [MS-ASEMAIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218806%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)